# Storing arrays of data in Apollo Link State

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm brand new to Apollo and am running into a problem that I'm not sure how to search online.

My goal is to store an array of objects in `apollo-link-state` that I would be able to access through queries from anywhere in my React app.
When I try to access a single string from Apollo's state it works but when I try to access the array of objects I get some strange entries in the console and the objects come in as undefined.

Here is a simplified Code Sandbox example of the problem I'm having:
https://codesandbox.io/s/xj8mr75nxw

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

For the sake of keeping a permanent record I'll display the code below as well:

**index.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import Client from "./Client";


class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={Client}>
        <Query query={CART_QUERY}>
          {({ data }) => {
            const { test, itemsInCart } = data;

            // Why isn't the data coming in the way I expect?
            // test works
            console.log(test);
            // itemsInCart does not... Why?
            console.log(itemsInCart);

            return (
              <div>
                {itemsInCart.map((product, i = 0) => (
                  <div style={{ margin: "50px 20px" }} key={i++}>
                    <p>{`Name is: ${product.name}`}</p>
                    <p>{`Price is: ${product.price}`}</p>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Query>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}


const CART_QUERY = gql`
  query product {
    test @client
    itemsInCart @client
  }
`;


ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Client.js:**

```
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";


const defaultState = {
  // It works to pull this string into my app
  test: "this is a test string",
  // This is the array I want to pull into my app. Not working...
  itemsInCart: [
    {
      __typename: "item",
      name: "Product 1",
      price: "$10"
    },
    {
      __typename: "item",
      name: "Product 2",
      price: "$20"
    },
    {
      __typename: "item",
      name: "Product 3",
      price: "$30"
    }
  ]
};


const Client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "",
  clientState: {
    defaults: defaultState,
    resolvers: {}
  }
});


export default Client;
```

Again, thank you for any help you may be able to give!
My guess is I'm making a rookie mistake and someone will know immediately why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a selection set for `itemsInCart`. The key is not that this is an array, but that it resolves to an object (or an array of objects), which means you have to specify which fields on those objects you are requesting. If you did this for a server-side query, your query would actually blow up, but because of the way `apollo-link-state` derives state from the defaults, it ends up just resolving to undefined.

```
const CART_QUERY = gql`
  query product {
    test @client
    itemsInCart @client {
      name
      price
    }
  }
`;
```